# How to run multiple commands on docker container on startup?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I have **Flask** application container which has to run on port **5000**.

I also have a background process which is related to queue. This process has an infinite loop which is why I want to run it in background.

I'm using docker-compose.yml file for creating container. For now, I'm able to run only one command which is to make the flask server up.

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 5000`. I'm using the `command` option in docker-compose .

This is the command I want to run in background `python app/workload/services/queue_services.py > qlog.txt`.

When I put the background command first in `command`, the server is not coming up and I'm only seeing the output from background script.

When I put the `flask run` command first, the background script is not starting at all.

Is there any proper way to run these two commands on container start up?

Comment: Generally you’d run the other command in a second container.  Is there any specific reason it must be in the same container?

Comment: As per the requirement that I'm working on, they have to be on a same container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python app/workload/services/queue_services.py > qlog.txt &
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

and set it as your command

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:5000", "--workers=1", "wsgi"]
```

in DockerFile

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use a program like supervisord. This way, we can scale it to multiple services without ever modifying the Dockerfile

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

I have compiled an image with supervisord and jre. 
https://hub.docker.com/r/palashgoel/supervisord-jre